# jQuery Validation Fields:getting error messages to disappear upon entering valid information

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

My code below gets the messages to appear and disappear once the information is entered but I want the error messages to show up ONE at a time even if I have multiple fields to validate. Right now all validation shows up upon clicking the button.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <br>
    <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" required> <span class="error" id="first_error"></span>

<label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" required> <span class="error" id="last_error"></span>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#mysubmit").click(function(){
    var myFirstName = $("#first_name").val().trim();
     $("#first_name").val(myFirstName);

    var myLastName = $("#last_name").val().trim();
     $("#last_name").val(myLastName);

    var myFirstNameError = $('#first_error').val();
    $('#first_error').val("");

    if(!myFirstName)
     {
         $("#first_error").html("You must Enter a First Name");  
     }
     else
     {
          $("#first_error").html("");
     }

     if(!myLastName)
     {
         $("#last_error").html("You must Enter a Last Name");    
     }
     else
     {
          $("#last_error").html("");
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you. Next time Make your code readable and post full code without any syntactical errors like bracket closing or manual errors like no submit buttons etc

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#mysubmit").click(function(){
    var myFirstName = $("#first_name").val().trim().length;
    // $("#first_name").val(myFirstName);

    var myLastName = $("#last_name").val().trim().length;
    // $("#last_name").val(myLastName);

    //var myFirstNameError = $('#first_error').val();
    //$('#first_error').val("");

    if(myFirstName>0)
     {
         $("#first_error").html("");  
     }
     else
     {
          $("#first_error").html("You must Enter a First Name");
     }

     if(myLastName>0 || !myFirstName>0)
     {
         $("#last_error").html("");    
     }
     else
     {
          $("#last_error").html("You must Enter a Last Name");
     }
     });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <br>
    <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" required> <span class="error" id="first_error"></span><br>

<label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" required> <span class="error" id="last_error"></span><br>
<button id="mysubmit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: first I apologize for the errors in syntax. Second, your code works well but I want each field to be validated one at a time. So when I first click the button, the first name error shows up and then the last name error does not appear until I enter a first name and then try to click the button without entering a last name. Any ideas?

Comment: Edited my code. Here the order of condition matters. Note it wisely.

Comment: Sorry No Emails, If you wanna ask something, you can post it here. More experienced developers are here to solve your issue. But research before you post anything.